# RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND Error on PayPal while calling subscription API

Tags: paypal, php-curl, paypal-subscriptions

I'm using a PayPal API for canceling subscriptions, It returns RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND error while canceling it. Basically, I have created plans and I have subscriptions IDs of each user. Here is the code snippet and result:

API Callback:

> `https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-DLXXXXXXXXX9/cancel`
> Blockquote

[image]

I just need to cancell the subscription fron this API, let me know if I'm doing anything wrong or I'm also ready with alternate solutions. Thanks in advance

Comment: Everything seems ok, but I encountered a similar error when the ID was incorrect. I am on my way to getting rid of paypal subscriptions, it seems incomplete and a mess.

Comment: Thanks @Divern - Actually it stores from Paypal IPN and seems file when I check on my PayPal sandbox account.